# NLog Only shows in RichTextBox the first time

Tags: nlog

I have a winform with a Rich Text box on it (LogView) and my configuration is set to log to that text box.  When I open the LogView from another form, then start logging everything works wonderful the first time.  When I try and open the LogView again, for a second run, nothing shows in the Rich Text box.

caller code

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LogView frm = new LogView();
        frm.Show(this);
        NLog.Logger logger = NLog.LogManager.GetLogger("");
        logger.Info("FORM 2 LOG");
    }
```

LogView code

```
    private void LogView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var logger = LogManager.GetLogger("");
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exception);
        }            //logger.Debug("test");
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        for (int i = 1; (i <= 100); i++)
        {
            // Perform a time consuming operation and report progress.
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            var logger = LogManager.GetLogger("");
            logger.Debug("i = " + i.ToString());
        }
    }
```

interestingly, doing it with this approach even the built-in NLog form doesn't work the second time.

I'm using version 2.0.1.0
.NET 4.5

Configuration

```
<nlog autoReload="true">
<targets>
  <target name="richTextBox"
          type="RichTextBox"
          controlName="richTextBox1"
          formName="LogView"
          useDefaultRowColoringRules="false"
          layout="${date} ${level} ${logger} ${message}"/>
</targets>
<rules>
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="richTextBox"/>
</rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: Could you post the configuration?

Comment: updated with the configuration

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the way NLog finds the RichTextBox.
When the configuration is first loaded (the first time a Logger is required), the RichTextBox target is initialized, meaning the RichTextBox is located and the target settings are stored in a cache. This means the reference would be wrong the second time the form is loaded.

This is related to the issue described at https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/133.

UPDATE:
You should be able to clear the cache by calling:

```
LogManager.Configuration.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
```

But remember this is an expensive operation

Comment: so how do I flush the cache?

Comment: You should be able to use LogManager.Configuration.ReconfigExistingLoggers()

Comment: I had tried this, but it didn't work, perhaps I'm not doing it at the right time?  Where would you suggest I do it, just before showing the form?

Comment: Just before the form should be okay.